# How to check in git to which branch was the last change made?

Tags: git, branch

Just cloned a git repo which has (besides the master branch) a lot of development branches. How can I tell which branch it was that the latest change was made to?

Most elegantly of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all commits by running `git log --all`. The first should be the latest commit. So you can list the branches that contain that commit with:

```
$ git branch --contains $(git log --oneline --all | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | head -n 1)
```